# Chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest - File upload at POST but requestBody.raw is empty

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use chrome extensions to get the body of the POST request when uploading a file and form data.

Using the following block of code:

```
/// background.js ///
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    // callback
    function (details) {
        if (details.requestBody.raw) {
            for (let i = 0; i < details.requestBody.raw.length; i++) {
                var postedString = decodeURIComponent(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(details.requestBody.raw[i].bytes)));
                console.log(postedString)
            }
        }
        return { cancel: false }
    },
    {
        urls: ["https://*/*", "http://*/*"]
    },
    ["blocking", "requestBody"]
);
```

But, I could not see the contents text of the uploaded file from the console(but I could only see the form data, message=Hello).

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryINmsBoKGn0M78aYv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"

Hello
------WebKitFormBoundaryINmsBoKGn0M78aYv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
```

manufest.json is following block of code.

```
{
  "name": "testo_plugin",
  "description": "Build an test_plugin!",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*"
  ]
}
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax? Or is it a specification of Chrome? (I could not find this specification)

Chrome version: 91.0.4472.114（Official Build） (64bit)

Comment: Sounds like a bug, see comment 12 in https://crbug.com/813285#c12.

Comment: Thank you very much. I checked and it appears to be the case.